# Why can't I set the full path inside angle brackets of the #include directive in Inno Setup?

Tags: include, inno-setup

Why does Inno Setup treat the following line as an error:

> `#include <C:\ABOfficeProjects\Install\InnoSetupProject\VCL_Styles\VCL_Styles.iss>`

[image]

Why can't I use angle brackets like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That problem turned to be a syntax highlighter bug which I've created a report for.

Here's the link: https://groups.google.com/g/innosetup/c/oZ87CLZyOXM

Comment: Fixed by https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/commit/5aa006115cfe8eac8551c174f92a05a038bc3d2a